# Where can I find articles about identity disclosure attack?

Tags: attack-prevention, identity, disclosure

Where can I find more details about identity disclosure attack and it's prevention?

If the adversary tries to steal the identity of an individual like mobile patterns and start appears in various locations. How can we detect them?

The intruder may change the data by listening to the victim for a very long time and try to simulate it, just like identity disclosure attack.

How can we identify the attacker, and can we able to report them to the central authority?

Comment: I'm little confused If its an identity theft, why the impersonator ever disclose to you or publicize the fraud?Unless the victim has been alerted by some kind of entity e.g bank.

Answer (score 1):

**Identity theft deterrent / strategy**

For some quick wins I suggest you read into NIST [initiative on National strategy for trusted identities in cyberspace](http://www.nist.gov/nstic/index.html)

To give you the quick summary of the program focus and objective it is to...

> The new Identity Ecosystem is meant for sensitive transactions — banking, shopping, accessing health records, etc. It is designed to protect your privacy by helping online providers verify your identity before accepting or providing sensitive information to you

This is where the real attacks happens and attacks that costs which is sometimes unquantifiable e.g reputation and trust.

**REPORTING**

I hope I have understood you correctly if you want some responsive authority to take action in case you experience some indications of fraud then depending upon the country you live and the laws that applies you can best contact local law agency. Like in case of USA FBI help you identify the fraudster through this online reporting system.

http://www.fbi.gov/about-us/investigate/cyber/identity_theft

If you are from USA then following agencies get involved when its comes to prosecution

Excerpt taken from [What Are Identity Theft and Identity Fraud?](http://www.justice.gov/criminal/fraud/websites/idtheft.html)

`Federal prosecutors work with federal investigative agencies such as the Federal Bureau of Investigation, the United States Secret Service, and the United States Postal Inspection Service to prosecute identity theft and fraud cases`.

**Responsible authority**
Also, taken from the excerpt

> Under the Identity Theft and Assumption Deterrence Act , the Federal Trade Commission is responsible for receiving and processing complaints from people who believe they may be victims of identity theft, providing informational materials to those people, and referring those complaints to appropriate entities, including the major credit reporting agencies and law enforcement agencies

[ONLINE REPORT FTC](http://www.consumer.ftc.gov/features/feature-0014-identity-theft)

Comment: impersonator never disclose to us or publicize the fraud, but the security system which we have or which can design should detect such kind of issues. I would get to know all the details of such paradigm.

Comment: So if your system is smart enough to detect fraud? then 50% job is done you just need to follow the protocol and take this thing with your organization legal team perhaps.

Comment: I guess if you want to know how can one design a system which best detects ID fraud, I'm afraid this requires more insight or perhaps another question.